# How to automate UI using python, pls any can share example

Tags: python

I have a web application I need to automate UI design Using python script

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)? It has python bindings. You can write python code to drive the browser.

Comment: I am looking full on python script only not integrating with selenium code

Comment: @testing What do you want to do? We cannot give you a full python script without knowing your purpose.

Comment: oh, ok give me the modules so that I can explore it